# Again "A Web Part or Web Form control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. " in editorPart project

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

I have a question concerning safe controls in Sharepoint development. I went through several proposed solutions for this problem but neither of them were able to fix the issue. What I basically did was to translate a C# project into VB one using Visual Studio 2010.

This project creates a Visual Web Part in Sharepoint and overrides a set of procedures/functions so you can get a dropdown list populated with SPP lists in the web editor part custom properties. The new VB projects seems free of bugs or translation errors because when I build the project I don't receive any warning/error. The solution deployment is correct, but when I try to use my web part in an empty spp page I receive the infamous message "A Web Part or Web Form control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe".

What I double-checked is the project visual web part "safe control entries" collection that contains the (supposed) correct entry with a valid Strong Name

I did several modification to this part of project; i.e., in the IIS web.config there is still an entry as `<safecontrols>` containing the same information found in "Safe control entries". I even created another empty project leaving all default names trying to avoid this kind of problem when you rename the Visual Web Part name but still with no luck.

### Update

Hi @Tome. If I can, I'll be more than happy to attach the source project.

@Adi, I cannot debug the application because my local Sharepoint refuse to use the web part because of the unsafe control.
For the chronicle, my SPP 2010 runs on top of a W2008 server in a virtual machine and I trust it works because this is not the first project I wrote. As I said I'm quite new in SPP developing but I know how to find the information I need in order to go over the issues I encounter while programming in a new environment (not this time, it seems).

The original C# project runs flawlessy but, evidently, I wrote some wrong lines during translation in VB. As you can see below, the project's file SharePointProjectItem.spdata contains the line tagged `<SafeControl>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectItem Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.VisualWebPart" DefaultFile="LeaveWebPartUserControl.ascx" SupportedTrustLevels="FullTrust" SupportedDeploymentScopes="Site" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2010/SharePointTools/SharePointProjectItemModel">
  <Files>
    <ProjectItemFile Source="Elements.xml" Target="LeaveWebPart\" Type="ElementManifest" />
    <ProjectItemFile Source="LeaveWebPart.webpart" Target="LeaveWebPart\" Type="ElementFile" />
    <ProjectItemFile Source="LeaveWebPartUserControl.ascx" Target="CONTROLTEMPLATES\LeaveApplicationVB\LeaveWebPart\" Type="TemplateFile" />
  </Files>
  <SafeControls>
    <SafeControl Name="SafeControlEntry1" Assembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" Namespace="LeaveApplicationVB.LeaveWebPart" TypeName="*" IsSafe="true" IsSafeAgainstScript="false" />
  </SafeControls>
</ProjectItem>
```

By the way, I'd give a try again this morning, rewriting every thing from scratch and see what I can get.

Comment: Please rewrite your question to be at least readable. And add samples of the code you wrote

Comment: You should run your code on the developer environment (your sharepoint server where the visual studio is located) and put some break points to see where it fails first, before you publish the solution to Production environement

Answer (score 0):

The issue raised by SPP concerning "unsafe control" was because, during C# project translation, I did include namespace identifiers as per C# syntax.

Removing namespace identifiers from VB code did solve the problem.
Now the project is able to create a custom editor part for my visual web part.